# R order geom_bar based on one level

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

How can I order the bar plot based on the first level of the variable `var`? *Now* the order is on the sum of the two bars *I would like to have it* ordered only by `value` where `var` is `"first"`. Below a working example.

```
library("ggplot2")
ct <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),  2)
var <- c("first","first","first","first","second","second","second","second")
value <- c(1,5,0.5,8,2,11,0.2,0.1)

df <- data.frame(ct, var, value)
df

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df
           , aes(x = reorder(ct, value)
                 , y = value
                 , fill = var
           )
           , stat = "identity"
           , position = "dodge"
           , width = .90 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `forcats::fct_reorder2()` you do not need to modify your `data.frame`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df
           , aes(x = forcats::fct_reorder2(ct, var=='first', value, .desc = F)
                 , y = value
                 , fill = var
           )
           , stat = "identity"
           , position = "dodge"
           , width = .90 ) + labs(x = "ct")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
df %>% # take the dataframe and then...
    group_by(ct) %>% # per group...
    mutate(order = sum(value * (var == "first"))) %>% # you calculate the sum of value where var is "first"
    ggplot(aes(reorder(ct, order) # ...and then plot everything.
               , value
               , fill = var)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity"
             , position = "dodge"
             , width = .9)
```

[image]